# Unity - Baseclass should get Information from Subclass

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make use of the MVC Pattern in Unity. I am a programming beginner.

Traps and moving Platforms use the same code so i created a base for them. I divide the code into "Data"-class and "Method"-class.

Both objects move to Point A, then to Point B, back to Point A and so on..
Point A and Point B got a trigger, to change the Movementdirection of the Platform/Trap.

The base class holds the data. The subclass gets the data and fills the base data. In the base class i have the object:

```
public virtual GameObject MovingObject { get { return null; } }
```

The subclass overrides the property returning null to make it return the right object. I try it this way:

```
[SerializeField]
    private GameObject movingObject;
    public override GameObject MovingObject { get { return movingObject; } }
```

The private variable is set in the Editor and sets the value to the property. This property gives the information to the base class. The problem is that i get null references and I do not know how to fix that. The base class does not return an object. The information get lost on their way to the base...

Is my logic wrong?

If you need to see the whole structure of these six classes you can look it up on

https://github.com/Garzec/MidnightFeast/tree/master/Assets/Scripts/MovingObjects

Sorry, i did not want to post all lines of code and unrelevant stuff :)

Comment: No need for virtual/override, you should make it all protected or public in the base.

If your base needs to know info from sub then member should be in base. it is not logic to have base requiring info from sub as base should work without sub.

Comment: How do you use the code? Can you show that please

Comment: Yes, you can see it on https://github.com/Garzec/MidnightFeast/tree/master/Assets/Scripts/MovingObjects there are all 6 scripts I use for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code. Assuming you will never need an instance of just a "MovingObjectsController" this looks like you need an abstract class as your base class. An abstract class cannot be instantiated, but it can require a child class (subclass) to implement abstract members, removing the need to return null in the parent. For example, you would define your controller as :

```
public abstract class MovingObjectsController
{
    protected abstract MovingObjectsData Data { get; }
}



public class PlatformController : MovingObjectsController
{
    private MovingObjectsData data;

    public PlatformController()
    {
        this.data = new MovingObjectsData(); //This being whatever data is specific to this object
    }

    protected override MovingObjectsData Data { 
        get 
        {
            return data; 
        }

    }
}
```

This way the child is required to implement whatever the parent needs, but the parent isn't required to provide a default implementation that doesn't make sense.